# add class to a word in a string dynamically Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

I want to add a class to a word in a string if it matches certain criteria

```
Your Bulk Creation: 8312e9, has Completed With Error. Please navigate to Outgoing Invoices> Create> Bulk History to view results.
```

I have this string, now if the string contains status as `CompletedWithError` then in the upper text I have to add a class to the word `Completed With Error`

The metadata for this is given below:

```
dateCreated: "2021-08-06T06:26:16.621Z"
 isError: false
 isRead: false
 message: "Your Bulk Creation: 8312e9, has Completed With Error. Please navigate to Outgoing Invoices> Create> Bulk History to view results."
 metaData: {
    recordType: "Invoice", 
    recordId: "610942b92c463500128312e9", 
    recordStatus: "CompletedWithError"
 }
```

The string is dynamic and can contain any other status as well, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: Can you show how you generate the string at the moment.

Comment: I have updated the question with the response from the API @hansmaad

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I am guessing i can do it with a function where i can check the string and if it contains the keywords then i have to do something to it @Kordrad
Not sure about it yet

Comment: @JuhiShaw If you have an idea of how to solve it, try that idea. Then, only after you've tried your idea, should you come to StackOverflow. :-)

Comment: 'I haven't tried it yet'  ? and why do you come on SO if you didn;t even try to solve it yourself ? :)

Comment: Ok
Will post the idea i tried
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could check to see if those strings exist if they do then return it as a boolean if its true then add it to the message with an add you could reformulate the response object - I left it as simple as possible.  Includes is case sensitive.

```
 if(message){
    const contains = message.includes('Completed With Error')
    
    if(contains){
  return  message + 'Has Completed With Errors'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it seems to work..

```
 public formatString(message: string, status: string): string {
        if (this.currentTab === this.notificationConstant.InvoicingSubTab && status === InvoiceStatus.CompletedWithError) {
           return message.split('Completed With Error').join("<span class='failed'>Completed With Error</span>");
        } else return message;
    }
```